# mdns hostname not fixed

Tags: hostname, avahi, mdns

I have a host that I named "betelgeuze". As such it is listed in /etc/hostname.

Avahi is mangling this:

```
boss@betelgeuze:/etc$ ps -ef |grep avahi
avahi        639       1  0 13:03 ?        00:00:02 avahi-daemon: running [betelgeuze-3.local]
avahi        682     639  0 13:03 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
boss        5263    3210  0 13:26 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto avahi
```

This way I cannot assume up front my host will be accessible through the name I expect (betelgeuze.local), because it is modified to betelgeuze-3.local.

Can I force it to `betelgeuze.local` in any way? I know (in concept) that the name presentation may change if duplicate names are suspected on the LAN, but all I need is a way that I can force the name to be changed back to the form I want it to.

Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf file so that it has a line:

`host-name=betelgeuze`

It will probably have

`#host-name=foo`

by default. Make sure you remove the # at the beginning of the line and reboot for the change to become effective.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you help me understand how the avahi service will use this to prevent modification?

Comment: @Unbeliever, I don’t know for sure that this change will prevent modification, however it makes sense to specify it explicitly for this machine. Nothing to lose by trying it.

Comment: roger dat. As long as there's no state change in the device like activation of  a second interface (like firing up wifi) it should stay stable. As a precaution though I've added a cronjob that restarts avahi-deamon every day. That also seems to bring it to the configured name in /etc/hostname